# slickjs always show arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I'm trying to config slick.js to show arrows in any circumstance.

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 6,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  arrows: true,
  centerMode: false,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```

The problem is when my slider hasn't enough slides do show (in my case, 6)
If the slider has less than 6 slides, the arrows don't show up.

I know the plugin  works like that, but for other reasons, i need to always show the arrows.

Anyone had to deal with something like that before ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle?

Comment: Just create your own arrows ;)
On the slick setting of `$('.slider-nav')` set `arrows: false` then make use buttons/link. On the onclick handler of buttons/links, use `.slickNext()` and `.slickPrev()`

Answer (score 8):

Make arrows:false and show arrow by your own

```
$('.container').slick({
   arrows: false,
});
```

and attach the events to arrows.

```
$('.next-arrow').on('click', function(){
   $('.container').slick('slickNext');
});
$('.prev-arrow').on('click', function(){
   $('.container').slick('slickPrev');
});
```

Comment: Note that the slick method syntax has changed, so now `$('.container').slickNext();` would need to be `$('.container').slick('slickNext');`

Comment: @Addison Thanks for the info. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `slidesToShow` to 0 if there is less than your default count of slides:

```
$(function() {
  var slides_count;
  slides_count = $('.slides .slide').length <= 5 ? 0 : 5;
  $('.slides').slick({
    slidesToShow: slides_count
  });
  if ($('.slides .slide').length <= 5) {
    return $('.slides .slick-next').addClass('slick-disabled').off('click');
  }
});

$('.slides').on('afterChange', function(slick) {
  if ($('.slides .slide').length <= 5) {
    return $(this).find('.slick-next').addClass('slick-disabled');
  }
});
```

Comment: If `slidesToShow` is set to `0` it gets stuck in an infinite loop creating infinite copies of the slides (regardless of the value of `infinite`).

Comment: @Gabriel At the moment I wrote this answer there was no infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `slidesToShow` to 1 at init to make sure the arrows created by slick.
2. Set the desired `slidesToShow` right after init.
3. If `slideCount` greater than `slidesToShow` then slick creates arrows click handlers itself, otherwise create additional handlers which simply forward clicks to slide elements.

```js
$('.product__slider-big-modal').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    infinite: false,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    draggable: false,
    speed: 500,
    asNavFor: '.product__slider-mini-modal'
});
const $slickPmm = $('.product__slider-mini-modal').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1, // always show arrows
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    speed: 500,
    infinite: false,
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    asNavFor: '.product__slider-big-modal',
    focusOnSelect: true
});
const slickPmm = $slickPmm[0].slick;
slickPmm.options.slidesToShow = 6; // set desired number after init
if (slickPmm.slideCount <= slickPmm.options.slidesToShow) {
    // handle arrows click 
    $slickPmm.find('.slick-next.slick-arrow').on('click', () => {
        $slickPmm.find('.slick-slide.slick-current').next().click();
    });
    $slickPmm.find('.slick-prev.slick-arrow').on('click', () => {
        $slickPmm.find('.slick-slide.slick-current').prev().click();
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to modified slick.js file in the or prevArrow and nextArrow(markup inside) events, check for slide length on init, and if it's 1 then hide the arrows.

Answer (score -2):

Hide it by CSS, works for me :

```
.slick-prev.slick-arrow.slick-disabled,
.slick-next.slick-arrow.slick-disabled {
    display: none !important; 
}
```